# Unable to install ffmpeg-php on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, video, ffmpeg

I downloaded **FFmpeg (version 2.2.3)** and compiled with **--disable-yasm** and **--enable-shared** configuration and installed.

I then downloaded **ffmpeg-php** extension from here - http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpeg-php/files/ffmpeg-php/0.6.0/

I was able to phpize and configure successfully.

**phpize output:**

```
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20121113
Zend Module Api No:      20121212
Zend Extension Api No:   220121212
```

**php --version output:**

```
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.4 (cli) (built: Sep  4 2014 06:56:34) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
```

But, when I try to make install my ffmpeg-php extension after successfully configuring, I am getting following error.

**Error log:**

```
/bin/bash /tmp/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/tmp/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/include -I/tmp/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/main -I/tmp/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0 -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/include/libavcodec/ -I/usr/local/include/libavformat/ -I/usr/local/include/libavutil/ -I/usr/local/include/libswscale/ -I/usr/local/include/libavfilter/ -I/usr/local/include/libavdevice/  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing   -c /tmp/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg-php.c -o ffmpeg-php.lo 
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/tmp/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/include -I/tmp/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/main -I/tmp/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0 -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/include/libavcodec/ -I/usr/local/include/libavformat/ -I/usr/local/include/libavutil/ -I/usr/local/include/libswscale/ -I/usr/local/include/libavfilter/ -I/usr/local/include/libavdevice/ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -c /tmp/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg-php.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/ffmpeg-php.o
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/stat.h:105:0,
                 from /usr/include/php5/main/php_streams.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/php5/main/php.h:396,
                 from /tmp/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg-php.c:40:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stat.h:91:21: error: field 'st_atim' has incomplete type
     struct timespec st_atim;  /* Time of last access.  */
                     ^
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stat.h:92:21: error: field 'st_mtim' has incomplete type
     struct timespec st_mtim;  /* Time of last modification.  */
                     ^
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stat.h:93:21: error: field 'st_ctim' has incomplete type
     struct timespec st_ctim;  /* Time of last status change.  */
                     ^
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stat.h:152:21: error: field 'st_atim' has incomplete type
     struct timespec st_atim;  /* Time of last access.  */
                     ^
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stat.h:153:21: error: field 'st_mtim' has incomplete type
     struct timespec st_mtim;  /* Time of last modification.  */
                     ^
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stat.h:154:21: error: field 'st_ctim' has incomplete type
     struct timespec st_ctim;  /* Time of last status change.  */
                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/php5/main/php_streams.h:28:0,
                 from /usr/include/php5/main/php.h:396,
                 from /tmp/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg-php.c:40:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/stat.h:365:31: error: array type has incomplete element type
         const struct timespec __times[2],
                               ^
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/stat.h:372:54: error: array type has incomplete element type
 extern int futimens (int __fd, const struct timespec __times[2]) __THROW;
                                                      ^
In file included from /usr/include/php5/main/php.h:402:0,
                 from /tmp/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg-php.c:40:
/usr/include/php5/TSRM/tsrm_virtual_cwd.h:218:2: error: unknown type name 'time_t'
  time_t                         expires;
  ^
/usr/include/php5/TSRM/tsrm_virtual_cwd.h:246:86: error: unknown type name 'time_t'
 CWD_API realpath_cache_bucket* realpath_cache_lookup(const char *path, int path_len, time_t t TSRMLS_DC);
                                                                                      ^
/tmp/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg-php.c: In function 'zm_startup_ffmpeg':
/tmp/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg-php.c:94:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'avcodec_init' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     avcodec_init();
     ^
make: *** [ffmpeg-php.lo] Error 1
```

How can I solve this? Or is there any other php library which can be used to extract all metadata of a video like bit rate, frame rate etc?

Comment: That ffmpeg-php is a dead project and hasn't been updated since 2008. How should it work with FFmpeg 2.2.3 which was released on June 2014? Do you even need a PHP extension? Why not execute `ffmpeg` itself from your scripts? Also see [Using FFmpeg from PHP Scripts](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Using%20FFmpeg%20from%20PHP%20scripts). Lastly, disabling Yasm support is not recommended; certain things will be slower without it.